# Proving that a system of equations has a unique solution

Tags: linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove this follow statement.

> Let $a,b,c,d,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose $ad - bc \neq 0$. Then there exists a unique $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
> \begin{align*}
> ax + by & = r \\ 
> cx + dy & = s. 
> \end{align*}

I'm trying to prove this without matrices, if that's at all possible, as I know this is really saying that the coefficient matrix is not invertible. Is there such a way? It's difficult to navigate the difference cases where on or more of $a,b,c,d,r,sr$ is $0$ but $ad - bc \neq 0$.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid proving it with matrices?

Comment: Well, I believe I know how to sort through the computation with matrices, but I don't think I truly understand the "why" of each step, so I'm hoping there's a different way to go about it.

Comment: I'd break into cases, $a\neq 0$ and $a=0$

Comment: Ok, I've posted a solution: Basically, if you write your system of equations as $A{\mathbf x}={\mathbf b}$, my method is equivalent to multiplying this matrix equation by $\mathrm{det}A.A^{-1}$.

Comment: Say that $(x,y)$ is a solution and $(x+p,y+q)$ is another solution. Prove that $p=q=0$ through substitution and elimination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ax+by=r$ and $cx=dy=s$ then $a(cx+dy) - c(ax+by)=as-cr$, that is, $(ad-bc)y=as-cr$, so $y$ must equal $\frac{as-cr}{ad-bc}$.

Then, by substituting this $y$ into one of the original equations, or by considering $b(cx+dy)-d(ax+by)$, you find that $x$ must equal $\frac{bs-dr}{ad-bc}$.

If there is a solution, then it is unique: $x$ and $y$ are as above. Substituting into the original equations will verify that this is, in fact, a solution.

Comment: Everything makes sense to me except for one step of simplifcation. I get $bx - dr = b(cx + dy) - d(ax + by) = (bc - ad)x$, and solving gives $x = \frac{dr - bx}{ad - bc}$. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: I think you mean $bs-dr=...$ and $x=\frac{dr-bs}{..}$, but yes, that's correct. My apologies.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. One more question: is it enough to say that because we've found explicit formulas for $x$ and $y$, the solution is unique? I tried to suppose there were solutions $(x,y), (x',y')$ and then establish that $x = x'$ adn $y = y'$, though it's rather messy.

Comment: Yes. We've proved that *if* there is any solution, it must be $x=\frac{yada}{ad-bc}$ and $y=\frac{blabla}{ad-bc}$.

That proves uniqueness, but not existence. 

To prove existence, we can prove that they are, in fact, a solution to the equations: (1) note these values for $x$ and $y$ are well defined as long as $ad\neq bc$, and (2) either (a) substituting these into the original equations, or (b) making sure the logic works backwards as well as forwards.

Comment: Suppose $(x,y)$ and $(x^\prime , y^\prime)$ are solutions, and let $(x^*,y^*)=(x-x^\prime , y-y^\prime)$. Since $ax+by=r$ and $ax^\prime+by^\prime=r$, it follows that $ax^\prime-ax+by^\prime-by=r-r$, that is, $ax^*+by^*=0$. Similarly, $cx^*+dx^*=0$. If any such $x^*$ and $y^*$ exist, they must equal $x^*=\frac{d.0-b.0}{ad-bc}=0$ and $y^*=\frac{a.0-c.0}{ad-bc}=0$. Thus $x^\prime=x$ and $y^\prime=y$.